# PHP Built-in Method to Get Array Values Given a List of Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an 'dictionary' array such as this:

```
  $arr['a']=5;
  $arr['b']=9;
  $arr['as']=56;
  $arr['gbsdfg']=89;
```

And I need a method that, given a list of the array keys, I can retrieve the corresponding array values. In other words, I am looking for a built-in function for the following methods:

```
function GetArrayValues($arrDictionary, $arrKeys)
{
  $arrValues=array();
  foreach($arrKeys as $key=>$value)
  {
     $arrValues[]=$arrDictionary[$key]
  }
  return $arrValues;
}
```

I am so sick of writing this kind of tedious transformation that I have to find a built-in method to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of keys as values you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) combined with [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). For example:

```
$values = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];
$keys   = ['a', 'c'];

array_intersect_key($values, array_flip($keys));
// ['a' => 1, 'c' => 3]
```