# Filter array by array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Built-in Method to Get Array Values Given a List of Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430708/php-built-in-method-to-get-array-values-given-a-list-of-keys)

Does PHP has built-in function for this purpuse?

I have two arrays, first associative with some data. For example:

```
$data = array(
    'name'      => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
    'address'   => 'NY, ...',
    'phone'     => '1234567'
);
```

And another array with keys:

```
$keys = array(
    'name', 
    'last_name'
);
```

After aplying this function I get only values from first array, which have keys from second array.

```
$result = function($data, $keys);
print_r($result);

// array(
//    'name'      => 'Jonh',
//    'last_name' => 'Smith'
// )
```

Comment: more duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array_intersect_key+is%3Aanswer

Comment: please use the search function before asking questions like you have been asked to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($data, array_fill_keys($keys, null));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $data = array(
      'name'      => 'John',
      'last_name' => 'Smith',
      'address'   => 'NY, ...',
      'phone'     => '1234567'
  );

  $keys = array('name', 'last_name');

 print_r(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keys)));
```

Comment: Care to comment your code, explain why you propose this snippet

Comment: @Yaroslav I proposed this snippet because it prints out the desired array and hence solves the question. Isn't StackOverflow about this? Why the downvote- do I miss something?

Comment: Steffen, yes, SO is about coding and some code is better than nothing. But if you comment your code it will be even more useful to the OP or any other future visitors, they will have a better understanding of it. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer. And for the downvote, it is anonymous so I can't tell you who downvoted, but is not mine for sure ;)

Comment: @Yaroslav Yes, to make my commentation as complete as the accepted and upvoted answer, I should have added a "Try the code below" (to make sure, the reader know it's not "Don't try the below" or "Ignore this post, there's no answer in it"). The article you mentioned states "Code is King- make sure it compiles" and "Code without an explanation is rarely useful, however". Mine is runnable. Since the OP just asked for the name of one concrete function I actually think commentary is negligible here. Different opinions. I find it sad, when correct answers are not honored but devalued.

Comment: I can't try the code, I'm not a php developer, so I can't upvote to contrarest the downvote you already have as I don't know if your code compiles or not. If you had some comments maybe, for example, I could have a better understanding of what are you doing and how you are doing it and then I could think "ok, I can't try the code but the reasoning is correct, let me upvote it". And last but not least. Yes, the accepted answer has only a "Try the below". So then you will not comment? Just because others don't comment?

Comment: @Yaroslav Just tried to point out how subjective this is. There's no reason for downvoting my answer. If you would execute it, it prints out the exact array the OP posted (see the // commented lines). Nevermind.

Comment: Have an upvote to contrarest the downvote, I trust you, and I believe so many replies on the comments defending your answer should be rewarded...nevertheless, try to add some comment when you can

Comment: @Yaroslav :-) Thanks. (Just in case you want to try out, run php in a linux-shell, type '<?php ', paste the code, then press enter and CTRL+d.)